# Filter HTTP Response with Express

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http, express

I'm building a simple polls app with express. My data looks like this:

```
var responseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    responseText: String,
    voters: []

})
module.exports = mongoose.model('Responses', responseSchema);

var pollsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    question: String,
    responses: [responseSchema],
})
```

Basically, in my routes, I get the ID from the route parameters and return an object containing the data from the appropriate poll. However, this object also contains an array of 'voters' which is a list of SessionID's that have voted for each possible response. I do not want this to be part of the response.

I would basically like to return everything, except for the 'voters' array. How can I 'filter' my http response so it contains everything except the voters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got some data structure with the `voters` array in it and you want to just remove that array, you can just do use `delete obj.voters` to remove that property from the returned object.

So, if you have some object like this:

```
var obj = {
    someField: someValue,
    someOtherField: someOtherValue,
    voters: [...]
}
```

You can remove the `voters` property from it with:

```
delete obj.voters;
```

---

FYI, if you're turning this database result into JSON and returning that from an Express route, then another approach would be to construct a new object for the actual http response and copy only the properties from the database query result object that you want to be in it. That might also involve a loop, but that makes your http response be a more deliberately built object rather than exactly what happens to be in your database.   It decouples the two.  If you add a new field to the database, it won't appear in the JSON from your route unless you consciously change your route to include it.   So, by default the route only returns the fields you explicitly made it return rather than defaulting to return everything in the database query result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
So, basically I'm going to need to write a loop to go through each response in 'responses' and delete the response.voters array?

I just feel like there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: @JamesMyers - yes, that would be one way to do it (should be only a few lines of code).  There are also some libraries that have functions for doing property filtering code *you're just off-loading the loop to a utility function).  The only other way I can think of would be to configure Mongoose differently so you can get the data you want without the voters info in it in the first place - I have no idea if that's possible by purely changing the query or whether you'd have to change the way it's being stored as I'm not a Mongoose person.

Comment: @JamesMyers - FYI, if you're turning this database result into JSON and returning that from an Express route, then another approach would be to construct a new object for the actual http response and copy only the properties from the database query result object that you want to be in it.  That would likely also involve a loop, but that makes your http response be a more deliberately built object rather than exactly what happens to be in your database.  If you add a new field to the database, it won't appear in the JSON from your route unless you consciously change your route to include it.

Comment: Thanks. I think I like your second response better. I'll go with that.

Comment: @JamesMyers - I added that second response to my answer.